# Basic usage of udisks

Tags: udisks

I'm on Ubuntu Mate 16.04. I would like someone to give me a short introduction to the basic usage of the udisks utility on Linux systems. Specifically, I would like to know how to properly mount and unmount an external USB drive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see connected devices do

```
lsblk
```

Identify the device you want to mount or unmount. USB devices will mount in /media so after you connect them you can identify them by their mountpoints. We can see the mounted device here is /dev/sda1

```
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    1 15.2G  0 disk 
└─sda1         8:1    1 15.2G  0 part /media/zanna/4C45-110F
```

to unmount this device:

```
udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sda1
```

`-b` stands for block device. After entering this command `lsblk` shows:

```
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    1 15.2G  0 disk 
└─sda1         8:1    1 15.2G  0 part
```

Now it's safe to remove. To re-mount it:

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda1
```

For general help type `udisksctl help` and for help on each command, type it and add `--help` for example:

```
udisksctl info --help
```

For information about my root partition I would type

```
udisksctl info -b /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

For more information type `info udisksctl`

Comment: I’d prefer a non-sudo alternative to the first command (not all users can use `sudo`), for example `lsblk`.

Comment: @Melebius thanks a lot for the super helpful comment - `lsblk` is much better for this :D